# error in pointer assignments in c on armv5

Tags: c, linux, arm, debian

I have the following code in c:

```
LinkedList
MemAllocLinkedList_add(MemAllocLinkedList self, void* data)
{
    LinkedList newElement = (LinkedList)
            MemoryAllocator_allocate(self->ma, sizeof(struct sLinkedList));

    if (newElement == NULL)
        return NULL; 

    newElement->data = data;  

    newElement->next = NULL; 

    LinkedList listEnd = LinkedList_getLastElement((LinkedList) self);

    listEnd->next = newElement;

    return newElement;
}
```

and

```
char*
MemoryAllocator_allocate(MemoryAllocator* self, int size)
{
    if (((self->currentPtr - self->memoryBlock) + size) <= self->size) {
        char* ptr = self->currentPtr;
        self->currentPtr += size;
        return ptr;
    }
    else{
        printf("MemoryAllocator_allocate: Out of Memory\n");
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

being LinkedList a pointer to sLinkedList that is:

```
struct sLinkedList {
    void* data;
    struct sLinkedList* next;
};
```

and MemAllocLinkedList a pointer to sMemAllocLinkedList that is:

```
struct sMemAllocLinkedList {
    void* data;
    struct sLinkedList* next;
    MemoryAllocator* ma;
};
```

I have a program who calls this 'MemAllocLinkedList_add' function several times without a problem, but there's one point where, within this function, the assignment 'listEnd->next = newElement' switches the first 16 bits with the las 16, so instead of having on listEnd->next 975912 I have -467140594 which leads to a SISEGEV error when I try to access to last element of that list later.

If I compile it and run it on a virtual machine with debian (intel 64bits) and on a raspberry pi (armv6 32 bits) it works perfectly fine. But when I try on a NanosG20 with armv5tej it does this thing that I've explained. I use gcc 4.6.

Anybody knows why this happens?

Thanks.

EDIT:

Here´s LinkedList_getLastElement :

```
LinkedList
LinkedList_getLastElement(LinkedList list)
{int i=0;
    while (list->next != NULL) {
        list = list->next; i++;     
    }
    return list;
}
```

Type MemoryAllocator:

```
typedef struct {
    char* memoryBlock;
    char* currentPtr;
    int size;
} MemoryAllocator;
```

This code is from libiec61850 an implementation of the standard 61850 for subelectric stations so there is a lot more code which is impossible to post here. I'm just posting the part where I get the error, but like I said, only on a board with ARMv5, not on the VM or the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: What does `LinkedList_getLastElement` do? Please show the type-aliases you've defined (the `typdef` declarations).

Comment: A small hint regarding your memory allocator, it can be simplified a little if you keep a pointer to the end of the memory area, then your check in the allocation function would just be e.g. `self->currentPtr + size < self->memoryBlockEnd)`

Comment: Your allocator doesn't look to be considering the correct alignment for the objects it's allocating, thus undefined behaviour as per the C standard. The ARMv5 unaligned access model of "round the pointer down to the nearest word, then rotate the data by the remainder" is always fun.

Comment: I tried with the "-munaligned-access" option on the compiler, but it says: "unrecognized command line option '-munaligned-access'".
Is there something else I can do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually have the same problem on all 3 platforms, it's just that on Intel and ARMv6 you get the "appearing to work correctly" form of undefined behaviour.

Here's a relevant quote from the C standard (6.3.2.3 in the n1256 draft of C99 I have to hand):

> A pointer to an object or incomplete type may be converted to a pointer to a different
>   object or incomplete type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the
>   pointed-to type, the behavior is undefined.

The notion of "correctly aligned" is defined by the ABI for the platform. In this case, the [ARM ABI](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042e/IHI0042E_aapcs.pdf) says thar `char` requires 1-byte alignment, and pointers require 4-byte alignment. Since `struct sLinkedList` consists of two pointers, it must also be aligned at least as strictly as a pointer.

Now, since `MemoryAllocator_allocate` naïvely increments its internal free pointer by `size` each time, there's no guarantee that the `char *` it returns is anything better than 1-byte aligned, thus converting that to a `struct sLinkedList *` leads to undefined behaviour in 3/4 possible cases. Since compilers tend to be more pragmatic than vindictive, rather than [nasal demons](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html) you got the undefined behaviour of "whatever the hardware does for unaligned loads/stores" upon dereferencing it, which may be an alignment fault, returning some nonsense data, or even returning the data you'd expect.

The solution is to make `MemoryAllocator_allocate` always round up `size` to the nearest multiple of the largest required alignment - for the ARM ABI, this is 8 bytes, although if you're sure you will *never* use any 64-bit types (like `double` or `long long`), you can probably get away with 4 bytes.

Comment: And commonly allocator code may use the lower bits (known to be aligned) to carry extra information.  A pointer is formed by masking.  This can lower the overhead of the allocator.  The active allocator block size should also be aligned similarly as you probably don't know what the caller will use the memory for (ie, another pointer needing the same requirements).  As well, you get cache benefits.

Comment: I couldn't have given a better answer. Nice job.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked and I learned something new. Thanks again!